# Как при помощи js изменить цвет блока по клику? И как спрятать по клику блок?

Tags: javascript, html5

Сделала кнопку:

`<a class="btn" href="#" onclick="change_color()">OK</a>`

И в css блок:

```
.child {
width: 60%;
height: 20%;
margin-right: 2%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`.child:last-child { margin-right: 0; }`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать чтобы этот блок менял цвет по клику? И какой код нужен для того, чтобы его скрыть по клику?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.child-colored {
  background-color: red;
}
.child-hidden {
  display: none;
}

function change_color() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.child').forEach(i => i.classList.add('child-colored'));
}
function hide_child() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.child').forEach(i => i.classList.add('child-hidden'));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, лучший

Comment: Поспешила, проверив только первый, а "скрыть" почему-то не работает..

Comment: @ExcciaSama Ну напишите, как Вы вызываете функцию `hide_child`.

Comment: Второй блок, который мне необходимо спрятать, называется child2. Это я добавила в css

`.child2-hidden {
  display: none;
}`
Это в js:
`function hide_child2() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.child2').forEach(i => i.classList.add('child2-hidden'));
}`

Это кнопка:
`<a class="btn" href="#" onclick="change_color()"> 
        <div class=".child-colored">
        <div class=".child2-hidden">
           OK</div></div></a>`

Может что-то напутала...

Comment: @ExcciaSama Где вызывается функция `hide_child2`? Нигде?

Comment: Ого, я разобралась, спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @ExcciaSama Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.